# Counting Unique Records With WHERE AND clause?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that looks like this

```
    id         |  segment_name
    ----------------------------------
    1          |  seg_1
    ----------------------------------
    2          |  seg_2
    ----------------------------------
    1          |  seg_2
    ----------------------------------
    3          |  seg_1
    ----------------------------------
    1          |  seg_3
```

And I want to be able to plug in 2 `segment_name`s into a SQL statment to find a count of unique ids. so for example if i passed in `seg_1` and `seg_2` in the SQL here is the desired output:

```
    count     
    ----------------------------------
    1        
    ----------------------------------
```

I am only counting the unique IDs that fall into the 2 `segment names` that I have defined.

ultimately I am looking for the segment overlap count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your original question, you just want `count(distinct)`:

```
select count(distinct id)
from t
where segment_name in ('seg_1', 'seg_2');
```

For the revised question:

```
select count(*)
from (select id
      from t
      where segment_name in ('seg_1', 'seg_2')
      group by id
      having count(*) = 2
     ) i;
```

Comment: doesnt IN do an OR? so there could be members that are just in one segment and not the other and the IN statement would count them?

Comment: @TjTate . . . Yes, that is what the question is asking for.  There are three ids that have one or the other segment.  Only one `id` has both segments.  If you have a different question, then ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: @TjTate . . . You updated the question after two people went though the trouble of answering the original question (both correctly).  You have invalidated the answers, and the can attract downvotes.

Comment: Oh, this answer makes a lot more sense now. Yes, I was about to downvote as an incorrect answer based on the desired output from the question.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the query you need?

```
select count(distinct id)
from t
where segment_name in ('seg_1', 'seg_2')
```

You changed the question. I think this query will answer the new one:

```
select count(distinct a.id)
from (
  select id from t where segment_name = 'seg_1'
) a join (
  select id from t where segment_name = 'seg_2'
) b on a.id = b.id
```

Comment: yes i did. tired and not thinking clearly apologies!

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) `count` FROM (
  SELECT id, COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY id) cnt
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE segment_name IN ('seg_1', 'seg_2')
) WHERE cnt > 1
```

It uses analytics function instead grouping or self joining